# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta a una función SQL al AZURE?

Tags: android, azure

Tengo realizada una app en Android Studio, y dentro de los requerimientos necesito traer datos de una función SQL en Azure.

¿Cómo puedo realizar la consulta directamente a la función? no he encontrado información acerca del tema.

Comment: No es recomendado hacerlo ya que los conectores no estan optimizados para eso, debes crear un servicio REST y consumirlo

Comment: ya revisaste la documentación Azure relacionada a la consulta de datos https://azure.microsoft.com/es-mx/services/sql-database/ ,  Te sugiero también revises [ask] modifiques tu pregunta para que obtengas mejores respuestas en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Consultar directamente desde una `app android` a la db en un servidor `cloud` no es recomendable, para eso existen los servicios `web api` que podrias exponer para acceder de forma segura a los datos.

Por otro lado una funcion sql no se puede ejecutar de forma directa, sino que lo realizas por medio de la ejecucion de un `EXEC` pero requieres asignar la respuesta a una variable, es por esa razon que se recomienda aplicarlo dentro de un `stored procedure`

[Execute User-defined Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/execute-user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017)

Por ejemplo en el articulo ejecuta la funcion definida `ufnGetSalesOrderStatusText`

```
DECLARE @ret nvarchar(15);   

EXEC @ret = dbo.ufnGetSalesOrderStatusText 
    @Status = 5;
```

la respuesta asignarda a la declaracion luego se podria:

- retornarlo como un parametro de salida del procedure
- devolverlo como un scalar usando el `SELECT`, al ser un valor simples usas el `ExecuteScalar()` de ado.net

Esta ejecucion seria la respuesta de la `web api` que consumes desde `android`

[Create backend services for native mobile apps with ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mobile/native-mobile-backend?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

por supuesto este servicio lo publicas en una `Web App` en `Azure`